# How do I have user input in this sqlite query with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

When I run this I get this error: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied. I have done a lot of other SQLite queries in this same program the exact same way just without the pandas part of it.

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Employees.db")
    self.df = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT units_granted FROM Officers 
        INNER JOIN Units ON Units.id_number_unit = Officers.id_number_off
        WHERE id_number_off BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 AND year_granted=?""", (year_granted_entry), conn)
```

Comment: A tuple with one element is written with an additional comma like `(1,)`. Also the parameters must be given in right order or as keyword parameters (see docs).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already tried putting them in a different order and adding a comma after, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Did this  self.df6 = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT units_granted FROM Officers 
   INNER JOIN Units ON Units.id_number_unit = Officers.id_number_off
   WHERE id_number_off BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 AND year_granted=?""", con, params=[(year_granted_entry)])